# Implement suggest function of elasticsearch-php client in my API

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement the suggest function of elasticsearch-php client in my API to suggest people some already existing problems.
I have made index for my problems

```
      'index' => 'newproblemindex',
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
                'number_of_shards' => 3,
                'number_of_replicas' => 2
            ],
            'mappings' => [
                'newproblems' => [ // type of index
                    '_source' => [
                        'enabled' => true
                    ],
                    'properties' => [
                        'title' => [
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'analyzer' => 'standard'
                        ],
                        'description' => [
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'analyzer' => 'standard'
                        ], 'suggest' => [
                            'type' => 'completion'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

But I am unable to find which param fields to use to implement suggest function

```
      'index' => 'newproblemindex',
        'body' => [
            'try' => [
                'text' => $request->search_key,
                'completion' => [ 'text' => 'suggest' ]
            ]
        ],
```

I am using laravel and taking search_key as request param but I am getting "invalid_type_name_exception" and when I tried to give the type name, it is again giving me some error.

```
      "suggest" => [
            "song-suggest" => [
                "prefix" => $request->search_key,
                "completion" => ["field" => "suggest"]
            ]
      ]
```

I am getting error "suggest is not a valid param ". Please help 
and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gey did you find a solution !!

Comment: No man @Ahmedbhs